# Sort user repositories by Stars Count in Github API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-api

I'm building a reactjs app to show a specific user repositories. I need to sort them by star count but i dont know how to do it in React.

This is the api url which gives me stars number: https://api.github.com/users/cesar/repos

This is my actual code:

```
const UserRepositories = props => (
  <div className="user-repos">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h2 className="repo-name">{props.repoName}</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p className="repo-description">{props.repoDescription}</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={Star} className="icon" />
          <span className="star-number">{props.starNumber}</span>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

And this is my map where i print the user repositories

```
    <div className="col-md-8">
      {githubRepo.map(name => (
        <UserRepositories
          key={name.id}
          repoName={name.name}
          repoDescription={name.description}
          starNumber={name.stargazers_count}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
```

Comment: If `githubRepo` is an array, maybe you can just use the `sort` function before calling `map`

Comment: @EmeraldCoder Its an array. But how i can implement the sort on map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your repositories using the `sort` function before calling the `map` function.

```
<div className="col-md-8">
  {
    githubRepo.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.stargazers_count > b.stargazers_count) return 1
      else if (a.stargazers_count < b.stargazers_count) return -1
      return 0
    }).map(name => (
      <UserRepositories
        key={name.id}
        repoName={name.name}
        repoDescription={name.description}
        starNumber={name.stargazers_count}
      />
    ))
  }
</div>
```